# Passing Data from JavaScript to php in same file

Tags: javascript, php, getdate

When I use `getDate()` in my php file, I always get time that lies 5 hours behind system time. So I use JavaScript getting time from system. My code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Date.prototype.today = function () { 
    return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"."+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"."+ this.getFullYear();
}

Date.prototype.timeNow = function () {
     return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getHours() +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() +":"+ ((this.getSeconds() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getSeconds();
}

var newDate = new Date();
var datetime = newDate.today() + " " + newDate.timeNow();
document.write(datetime);

</script>
```

It's a php file. Now I wanna use "datatime" in my php code

```
<?php
//Here I use datetime
?>
```

how do I use it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client side and therefore gets the client time. PHP runs on the server and therefore gets the server time. Both of these times should be correct in their contexts. You need to evaluate why you think you need to store the client's time on the server provided the clients may change time zones whenever they want.

Comment: Why not set the time in PHP and pass to JavaScript? Now you will have to Ajax the time to the PHP for to us unknown reasons

Comment: javascript is client side while php runs on the server , why you don't set your specific time zone within your php code ? [date_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not set your timezone with [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) (it will set the timezone globally) ?

```
<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Mauritius');
    $date= date('Y-m-d H:i');
    echo $date;
?>
```

Output :

> 2017-02-12 13:54

Or you could use php [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object :

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka"));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Output :

> 2017-02-12 16:19

EDIT :

Here is the list of php supported timezones : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

So, your timezone will be "**Asia/Dhaka**".

Comment: If i get time Dhaka Bangladesh What time zone I select.

Comment: @A.ANoman I edited my answer. Your timezone is "**Asia/Dhaka**"

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that.
the php script run in yor sever befor sending to users browser,
after this run the browser the javascript code in the users computer.

If all you need is a variable with date, use **date()** function in php with correct params For example:

```
$today = date("Ymd");
```

in defult php return month number in 2 digits.